# How can I call a mixin by reference in LESS?

Tags: less, less-mixins

The logical way would be:

```
.mymixin() {
  sample_key: samplevalue;
}

@avar:  mymixin;
.@{avar}();
```

but I get a parse error.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Module mixins

If you want to call a specific mixin by a reference from a variable you would need to use a parameter, as **you can not dynamicaly call parametric mixins by their names**. So, the closest to what you want to do, would be using module mixins.

It would look like this in **LESS**:

```
.mixin(mymixin) {
  sample_key:samplevalue;
}

.mixin(anothermixin) {
  another_key:anothervalue;
}

@avar: mymixin;
.mixin(@avar);
```

the output **CSS** will be as expected:

```
sample_key: samplevalue;
```

and if you would change `@avar` to `anothermixin` you would specifically call the second mixin.

Here makes @ScottS a great use of this approach:
**[LESS CSS Pass mixin as a parameter to another mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551313/less-css-pass-mixin-as-a-parameter-to-another-mixin/11589227#11589227)**

### Edit:

To elaborate the answer a bit further. ***Why your approach wouldn't work?*** The problem is in selector/rule interpolation, where the line needs to have the following structure:

```
.prefix-satring-@{classname} some-more-string { property:value; }
```

so you can not call a mixin with it as it expects a `{` after the selector name and also an unescaped `(` is not accepted as valid syntax in rule interpolation.

**Additional info:**

Similarly, you can not dynamically generate property names in LESS. So you can not do anything like `.myclass{-webkit-@{property}:value;}`, where this is possible in [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) (another very popular preprocessor language). However, there are some workarounds for [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868042/using-an-argument-for-tag-name-in-less/15443008#15443008).

Another issue, that might be of notion here is that the interpolated classes (e.g. `.@{avar}{something:something;}`) get directly rendered into CSS and do not exist as LESS object/mixins, that you could [reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137465/less-css-reuse-generated-name-class-as-a-mixin).

Comment: You are passing a parameter to the mixin. What I am asking is calling a mixin whos name is the value of a variable.

Comment: You can not do that in LESS. The only way how you can reference a mixin dynamically is by passing a speciffic parameter, so I think it is not really fair that you down-voted my answer.