# LESS mixin a variable class name

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome 4.0.0, and want to do something like this in LESS:

```
.btn-github {
  .btn;
  .btn-primary;
  margin-left: 3em;

  i {
    .@{fa-css-prefix};
    .@{fa-css-prefix}-github;
    .@{fa-css-prefix}-lg;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
}
```

That doesn't compile with the error:

`ParseError: Unrecognised input in - on line ...`

Is it possible to accomplish this? It would certainly make a beautiful button for me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are at least 2 problems with what you are trying to do (***for LESS >=1.6 see update bellow***):

**1) Unfortunately it is not possible to call a mixin using selector
    interpolation.**

With selector interpolation LESS expects the construct to be of
   following format:

```
.@{selector-string} { property:value; }
```

(the interpolated selector can have also some static string pre or
    post the interpolation)

so

```
.@{selector-string};
```

is *Unrecognised* by the LESS compiler. See more here:
[How can I call a mixin by reference in LESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506146/how-can-i-call-a-mixin-by-reference-in-less/16506448#16506448)

**2) A ruleset with an interpolated selector gets directly printed to the CSS output and does not exist as a mixin that you could reuse in the LESS run**

For example:

```
@foo: test;

.@{foo} {
  length: 20px;
}

.bar {
  .test;
}
```

will return:

```
    Name error: .test is undefined
    .bar {  .test;}
```

See more on that here: [LESS CSS: Reuse generated .@{name} class as a mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137465/less-css-reuse-generated-name-class-as-a-mixin/15142547#15142547)

Possible solution for your problem would be redifinig the font awesome rules as some kind of reusable mixins (without using interpolation). Something like this:

```
@fa-var-github: "\f09b";

.fa-mixin() {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-mixin-lg() {
  font-size: (4em / 3);
  line-height: (3em / 4);
  vertical-align: -15%;
}
.fa-mixin-icon(@icon){
  @var: "fa-var-@{icon}";
  &:before { content: @@var; }
}
i {
  .fa-mixin;
  .fa-mixin-lg;
  .fa-mixin-icon(github);
}
```

If you don't really need the variables and just want to include the rules, the best way would be just to **import the compiled CSS** version of the FontAwesome (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394032/less-using-font-awesome-in-before/20395403#20395403)):

```
@import (less) 'font-awesome.css';
```

and then you can just use the CSS rules like LESS mixins or extend their selectors as you see fit and it should work perfectly.

---

#### Update:

As of **LESS >= 1.6** rules with interpolated selectors can be accessed as mixins ... so the #2 limitation form above does not apply anymore (but you still can not call a mixin dynamically with interpolation). So you can simply call LESS mixins and variables from the imported `font-awesome.less` file like so:

```
i {
  .fa;
  .fa-lg;
  &:before{
    content: @fa-var-github;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 awesome ... very nice explanation, deserves to be up-voted. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Only reason not to was that I have this same button in many places, and wanted to centralize the styling. Thanks again!

Comment: One reason to want a mixin (and the reason we need it) is that sometimes you're dealing with html that is generated outside of your control; for example by a JS plugin. You'll need to be able to apply them through pure CSS in those cases.