# LESS: using font-awesome in :before

Tags: html, css, less, pseudo-element, font-awesome

I want to have a CSS selector for a header with custom font, color and a bullet to the left. So I want my header to use my custom font, and it's `:before` pseudo-element to use font-awesome. So I would like my `:before` to have the `.fa` class, while the whole element doesn't have this class.

I have this html: `<h1 class="bulleted-header">Hello</h1>` And I would like to write something like this in LESS:

```
.bulleted-header {
    color: #61cbe6;
    font: 16px 'ds_goose', sans-serif;
    &:before {
        content: @fa-var-bullseye; // font-awesome's bullet icon
        .fa; // calling font-awesome's class. DOESN'T COMPILE
    }
}
```

The problem is that `.fa` class is declared like this in font-awesome LESS sources: `.@{fa-css-prefix} { ... }`, so the code above doesn't compile. I tried to reuse the `.fa` code like this:

```
&:before {
    content: @fa-var-bullseye; // font-awesome's bullet icon
    .@{fa-css-prefix}; // DOESN'T COMPILE
}
```

and like this:

```
&:before:extend(.@{fa-css-prefix}) { // compiles but no effect
    content: @fa-var-bullseye; // font-awesome's bullet icon
}
```

I know I can just change my html like this `<h1 class="bulleted-header"><span class = "fa fa-bullseye"></span>Hello</h1>` and not to use `:before` at all, but it's more logical to keep all this bullets thing in CSS.

I ended up just copy-pasting the content of `.fa` into my `:before`, but there is something wrong in this approach because now I have to maintain this code myself in case FA guys change something. Are there any more elegant solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS mixin a variable class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602812/less-mixin-a-variable-class-name)

Answer (score 11):

You can not really use interpolated selectors for mixins in Less ... so the rules with interpolated selectors can not be included in other rulesets. See answer here:

[LESS mixin a variable class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602812/less-mixin-a-variable-class-name/19603404#19603404)

But in your case you could just **import the compiled css** as less instead of the less files, if you are not doing any other special stuff with these less files. Simply by using:

```
@import (less) 'font-awesome.css';
```

Then you can use `.fa` as a mixin, exactly like you wanted.

However, this way you don't import the character variables, which you could do separately, but instead you could also just use `content: "\f140";` directly (the way it's used in `.fa-bullseye:before`)

Or alternatively just **extend** the selectors imported from `font-awesome.css` with your selector, like so:

```
.bulleted-header {
    color: #61cbe6;
    font: 16px 'ds_goose', sans-serif;
    &:extend(.fa, .fa-bullseye all);
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

#### Update:

As of **LESS >= 1.6** rules with interpolated selectors can be accessed as mixins. So calling `.fa` as a mixin, like you do in your above example, should now work perfectly.

Comment: Don't forget to add the `font-family: FontAwesome;` if you are manually inserting things like `content: "\f140";`.

Comment: @ratata it is the the escaped hex representation of the character and in this case it is an extension of the unicode set. In html a hex value representation looks like this `&#x<value>;` , but In CSS you use just the escaped hex value `\<value>`. You can use the hex representation of any unicode character in the same manner (see a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/te55k46r/)). Most ASCII/Unicode character tables will also list the hex codes. Here is the font awesome cheat sheet with all the codes (in their html form): http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: Also with gulp-less I've had to use @import (less) 'font-awesome.css';

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the SASS-implementation. I changed the `.@{fa-css-prefix}` code so it does `.@{fa-css-prefix}:before` and this worked pretty fine for me. You still have to extend your base element then, but the font-style is only applied to the :before

I actually wondered why they did it like that. I think their approach was that you have single dom elements for every icon (like the `<i>` they use) and no icon in front of a button, link, list item or whatever as you would usually do it. But as far as I remember this was the case in the last fontawesome version.