# use variables on mixin or extend in Less.js

Tags: css, less

Using variable on `mixin` or `extend` in `Less.js` as follow will throw error.

```css
@bar : bar;

.@{bar} {
  background: yellow;
}

// ParseError: Missing closing ')'
.foo {
  .@{bar}(); 
}

// Not work
.jam {
  &:extend(.@{bar});
}
```

Has `Less.js` a proper syntax to call `mixin` with variables?

Comment: In short, no. The corresponding feature for `extend` is proposed at [#1485](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1485).

Comment: As for mixins - these days it's not really recommended to re-use existing CSS rulesets as mixins for various reasons, so this feature is not planned (though it will be probably supported indirectly by other additions). Thus for your use-case you're probably better to start with something [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40bar%20%3A%20bar%3B%5Cn%5Cn.style-to-reuse()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20yellow%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.%40%7Bbar%7D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.style-to-reuse()%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.style-to-reuse()%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call a mixin using selector interpolation, [which is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602812/less-mixin-a-variable-class-name).

As for extend, Less documentation [states it clearly](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-selector-interpolation-with-extend):

> Extend is NOT able to match selectors with variables. If selector contains variable, extend will ignore it.