# LESS mix a variable in a class

Tags: html, css, variables, less

What is the correct way to mix a LESS variable in a class within LESS itself. I've tried it like this:

.btn-@juicer-popup-button-color();

and

.btn-@{juicer-popup-button-color}();

Both options don't seem to work...
the outcome should be something like .btn-red(); Where red is stored in the variable @juicer-popup-button-color.

**For example:**

```
@juicer-button-color: red;

.juicer-button {
  font-weight: bold;
  .btn();
  .btn-lg();
  .btn-@juicer-button-color(); //this one
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

and the outcome should be

```
.juicer-button {
  font-weight: bold;
  .btn();
  .btn-lg();
  .btn-red(); //this one
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: You mean append a variable's value in the selector? If yes, `.btn-@{juicer-popup-button-color}{ property: value; }`.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602812/less-mixin-a-variable-class-name) could help you.